# Как посчитать среднее арифметическое в каждой строке из текстого файла?

Tags: java, text, числа

есть файл, в котором:
12 3 5
11 3 4
13 4 5

(11, 12, 13 - порядковые числа студентов, а сбоку оценки).
Надо посчитать среднее арифметическую оценку каждого ученика.
Знаю как посчитать общую сумму чисел :

```
Scanner grades = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
   int sum=0;
   int srednee=0;
   int count=0;

   while(grades.hasNext()){
   int number=grades.nextInt();
   count++;
   sum=number+sum;}
   srednee = sum/count;

    System.out.println(srednee);
```

Но здесь еще надо подсчитать каждую строку в отдельности и , наверное, пропускать первое число, чтобы в итоге получилось:
12 4
11 3,5
13 4,5
Прошу совета, джентельмены!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("output.txt"));
     Stream<String> reader = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))) {

     reader
           .forEach(e -> {
                    String[] numbers = e.split("\\s|[,]");
                    int studentNumber = Integer.valueOf(numbers[0]);
                    double average = Arrays
                            .stream(numbers)
                            .skip(1)
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(IntSummaryStatistics::new,
                                     IntSummaryStatistics::accept,
                                     IntSummaryStatistics::combine)
                            .getAverage();

                    try {
                        writer.write(String.format("%d %f", studentNumber, average));
                        writer.newLine();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }});
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А всегда при работе с файлами нужно пользоваться try catch ?

Comment: Можно не обрабатывать а прокидывать вверх или игнорировать, но в данном коде try-catch скорее не про исключения а про автоматическое освобождение ресурсов

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Double> map = Files.lines(Paths.get("grades.txt"))
                                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                                .map(s -> s.split("\\s"))
                                .map(Arrays::asList)
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i.get(0),
                                                          i -> i.subList(1, i.size())
                                                                .stream()
                                                                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                                                                .summaryStatistics()
                                                                .getAverage()));
```